# Break visual line without hard breaking line

Tags: line-breaks, wrap

Is it possible to break visual line without breaking line? For example:

```
Some text blah blah "insert visual break"
"cursor now here" keep writing. But both these sentences is one wrapped line.
```

Visually it would be same behavior as regular `<CR>` line break. But without new line characters inserted.

I can imagine a brute force solution, if tw=80, count the number of character spaces from cursor to textwidth limit 80, insert that many blank spaces.

Comment: Welcome to Vi&Vim SE. Your question is a little hard to follow. Particularly the second paragraph. If you could reformat (e.g. surround text you see on the screen with backslashes) so commentary is separate from Vim output it should help.

Comment: @BLayer means backticks

Comment: Yes, DBK, is correct. These: ` `. My bad.

Comment: The `linebreak` option seems like the right direction: [http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'linebreak'](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'linebreak')